# No provider for MatExpansionPanel if used inside child component in *ngFor

Tags: angular

I want to separate my mat-accordion from each of the mat-expansion-panel using child component.

my app.component.html looks like this:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let customer of customers">
    <app-customer [name]="customer"></app-customer>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

My child component looks like this:

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header>
      {{ name }}
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

When i start the application i get the following error in console (and nothing is displayed)

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
No provider for MatExpansionPanel ("[ERROR ->]<mat-expansion-panel-header>
      {{ name }}
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
"): ng:///AppModule/CustomerComponent.html@0:0
```

What am I doing wrong? If I don't use a child component, it works okay

Comment: Is your child component declared in a module that does import MatExpansionModule?

Comment: I only have one module. app.module.ts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing this solved the problem to me, by adding it in the component declarations.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-x',
  templateUrl: './app-x.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-x.scss'],
  viewProviders: [MatExpansionPanel]
})
```

Comment: Nice, although it is advisable to understand what the different providers are.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work for me, even though my situation is quite similar. Adding MatExpansionPanel to the viewProviders also means I have to auto-import it from @angular/material/expansion?
The error disappears, but my view is empty.

Comment: @fonzane could be the version issue I don't rem. which version of @angular/material I was using when I wrote this answer :)

Comment: @DivyanshuRawat I've marked the answer as correct since I do see the DOM updated (and the app now compiles) but as fonzane said, I can't see anything. My material is v12

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put it in child component, you need to add the mat-expansion-panel to the child component like so:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let customer of customers">
    <app-customer [name]="customer"></app-customer>
  </ng-container>
</mat-accordion>
```

and then in your child component:

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      {{ name }}
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: This is not what I waned to do. I wanted to separate the mat-accordion for the child components

Answer (score 0):

For future seekers, check you didn't forgot to add `<mat-expansion-panel>` before `mat-expansion-panel-header`.

That was my cause and the error was the same as the question's title.